# How to fetch data of one field from pre-saved data on another field in Django Admin?

Tags: django, model, admin

I am trying to make a simple management software that tracks payment from students.

**models.py**

```
class Class(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject')
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('Teacher', related_name='teaching')
    timeslot = models.ForeignKey('TimeSlot')
 -> fee = models.IntegerField()

class StudyClass(Base):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student')
    a_class = models.ForeignKey('Class')

class Payment(Base):
    study_class = models.ForeignKey('StudyClass')
    session = models.ForeignKey('Session')
 -> amount = # maybe there should be an IntegerField over here or a method
```

The fee for a class is saved in the Class model, however, I need to save it in Payment model as a payment is made. When the user is using Django Admin, how can I pre-populate the `amount` field in `Payment` model from the value of `fee` field in `Class` model.